# Authorize.net integration with Mastercard ASI - Zero preauth transaction is failing with error code 290

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am trying to make a authOnlyTransaction with amount 0 to cater Mastercard ASI requirements.
The transaction is failing with transaction error code 290 (There is one or more missing or invalid required fields.) and resultCode "ERROR" with code "E00027"

I am able to make successful transaction if I change the amount to a non zero value.

Environment: Sanbox 
Request data structure:

```
{
  "merchantAuthentication": {
    "name": "-removed-",
    "transactionKey": "-removed-",
    "sessionToken": null,
    "password": null,
    "impersonationAuthentication": null,
    "fingerPrint": null,
    "clientKey": null,
    "accessToken": null,
    "mobileDeviceId": null
  },
  "clientId": null,
  "refId": "12345",
  "transactionRequest": {
    "transactionType": "authOnlyTransaction",
    "amount": 0.00,
    "currencyCode": null,
    "payment": {
      "creditCard": {
        "cardNumber": "4242424242424242",
        "expirationDate": "0822",
        "cardCode": "123",
        "isPaymentToken": null,
        "cryptogram": null,
        "tokenRequestorName": null,
        "tokenRequestorId": null,
        "tokenRequestorEci": null
      },
      "bankAccount": null,
      "trackData": null,
      "encryptedTrackData": null,
      "payPal": null,
      "opaqueData": null,
      "emv": null,
      "dataSource": null
    },
    "profile": null,
    "solution": null,
    "callId": null,
    "terminalNumber": null,
    "authCode": null,
    "refTransId": null,
    "splitTenderId": null,
    "order": null,
    "lineItems": null,
    "tax": null,
    "duty": null,
    "shipping": null,
    "taxExempt": null,
    "poNumber": null,
    "customer": null,
    "billTo": null,
    "shipTo": null,
    "customerIP": null,
    "cardholderAuthentication": null,
    "retail": null,
    "employeeId": null,
    "transactionSettings": null,
    "userFields": null,
    "surcharge": null,
    "merchantDescriptor": null,
    "subMerchant": null,
    "tip": null,
    "processingOptions": null,
    "subsequentAuthInformation": null,
    "otherTax": null,
    "shipFrom": null
  }
}
```

Response:

```
    {
      "refId": "12345",
      "messages": {
        "resultCode": "ERROR",
        "message": [
          {
            "code": "E00027",
            "text": "The transaction was unsuccessful."
          }
        ]
      },
      "sessionToken": null,
      "transactionResponse": {
        "responseCode": "3",
        "rawResponseCode": null,
        "authCode": "",
        "avsResultCode": "P",
        "cvvResultCode": "",
        "cavvResultCode": "",
        "transId": "0",
        "refTransID": "",
        "transHash": "0361773D30A57757263264653B9B5EAA",
        "testRequest": "0",
        "accountNumber": "XXXX4242",
        "entryMode": null,
        "accountType": "Visa",
        "splitTenderId": null,
        "prePaidCard": null,
        "messages": null,
        "errors": {
          "error": [
            {
              "errorCode": "290",
              "errorText": "There is one or more missing or invalid required fields."
            }
          ]
        },
        "splitTenderPayments": null,
        "userFields": null,
        "shipTo": null,
        "secureAcceptance": null,
        "emvResponse": null,
        "transHashSha2": "9BE4002C112F9674B30F6202138EE717C23383A7B422912D27EDA6C4ACB0EFBF5764FDAF9B67A5F6AF33DCEFD857581A22DD12BFD1961FE17465AF7412173C0C",
        "profile": null,
        "networkTransId": null
      },
      "profileResponse": null
    }
```

Comment: I managed to make a successful request with amount 0  by providing data for "billTo" input parameter.

"billTo": {
            "address": "14 Main Street",
            "zip": "44628"
         }

The address and zip fields seems mandatory if the amount is zero. For non zero amounts, they are optional.